# jQuery.autocomplete doesn't show value returned from jQuery.ajax

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery

I have the following code.

The ajax query works, and the data returned from the server is a valid json.
I succeeded to make the autocomplete dropdown work with a remote data source, through a request like this : http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote.

My problem is that the data returned from the jquery.ajax doesn't show in the autocomplete.  Anyone can help? thks.

```
jQuery( "#input_2_5" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "url/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{
                action: 'word_autocomplete'
            },

            success: function(data) {
                return data;
            }

        });

    }

});
```

Comment: Take a look at the next example http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: Looks like you have to set the label and value fields using the data that was returned..

Comment: I started from that example to build my function, but I can't make it work.  I don't need to reprocess my data since it's already in the right format for the autocomplete.

Comment: You have to call the `response` function with each element of the returned data, you can't just return the data. See the example @sofl linked to.

Comment: Thanks all, you pointed the problem and I solved it. I will post the answer  later since I have less than 10 reputation points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery( "#input_2_5" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response){

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "url/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{
            action: 'word_autocomplete'
        },
        success: function (data) {
                if (data.d != null) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item.name
                        }
                    }));
                }

            }
    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

This formulation worked for me:  Mine was a jsonp request, but this should do it:

```
jQuery( "#input_2_5" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "url/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: 'searchterm=' + request.term,
                        success: function( data ) {
                            response( $.map( data, function ( item ) {
                        return item;
                    }));

                        }
    });
```

Obviously your server side should be looking for '*searchterm*' in the query string...